# Remove default growl messages

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, growl

I am using primefaces and p:inputText fields that are required, I use global p:messages to display the required info, and growl only from the back end bean. However, on check are displayed both the p:messages and the default p:growl error messages for required fields. Does anyone know how to disable the default growl messages?

```
<p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true"/> 
<h:form id="addUser"> 
<p:growl id="newmessage" showDetail="false" globalOnly="true" /> 
<p:inputText id="name" value="#{manageUser.user.name}" required="true" />
```

and in my backing bean

```
if (uf.checkUsernameAvailability(user.getLogin())) { FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Error", "Username already exists!"));}
```

I don't understand why they keep appearing if they are not defined.

Answer (score 1):

The `p:growl` and `p:messages` by default display all messages, or global only messages if the attribute is set.

However, both components have another nice attribute `redisplay` that you could use. Quote from the [taglib documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.2/):

> Defines if already rendered messages should be displayed. Default is
>   true.

Set this to false for the component that displays already rendered messages:

```html
<p:growl id="newmessage" showDetail="false" globalOnly="true" 
         redisplay="false" />
```

Comment: Could you please move your code to your question (the edit-link below the question)? It is hard to read inside a comment.

Comment: I tried this and it's not the problem since on the other page I don't have p:growl only p:messages and the growl message still appear.